# Travis CI cache: ignore specific folder/file from cache

Tags: node.js, caching, travis-ci

I have the following configuration in my `.travis.yml`:

```
language: node_js
node_js:
- '5.0.0'
sudo: false
cache:
  bundler: true
  directories:
  - node_modules
```

One of my packages is a Github branch where content changes but version remains unchanged. What happens is that the cache is not invalidated, and there is nothing wrong at this point. But I wonder if there is a way to exclude a specific folder from the cache construction, something along these lines:

```
language: node_js
node_js:
- '5.0.0'
sudo: false
cache:
  bundler: true
  directories:
  - node_modules
  - !node_modules/grommet
```

Where `!node_modules/grommet` will be excluded from the cache index.

I tried using `before_cache` as described in [here](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/caching/#before_cache-phase). But no luck.

Any help appreciated...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to reinstall the module manually. In your case, your `travis.yml` `install` section should look like this:

```
install:
  - npm uninstall grommet
  - npm install
```